# Implements a custom CellEditor for a JTable with 2 columns (String, Integer) and n Rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I have a JTable with N rows and 2 columns I need to implement a custom CellEditor class to access the data input of each cell with

`table.getCellEditor(int row, int column).getCellEditorValue()`

I have used this CellEditor class

```
class MyEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JTextField textField;
        private boolean valueSet;
          public MyEditor() {
            super(new JTextField());
          }

          @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject eo) {
                System.err.println("isCellEditable");
                if (eo instanceof KeyEvent) {
                    KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent) eo;
                    System.err.println("key event: " + ke.getKeyChar());
                    textField.setText(String.valueOf(ke.getKeyChar()));
                    valueSet = true;
                } else {
                    valueSet = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
    }
```

but is not enough to access the data in the right cell position... (and seems that all the table is seen as a whole cell)

all the example that I have found are relative to using cell editor to block the editing cell if the input is not correct but anything clear enough to help me to solve the problem.

PS
If you want try to see in detail how the whole interface (not)works the whole code is this:

```
public class CompileDataJob extends JFrame {
      private boolean DEBUG = false;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CompileDataJob frame = new CompileDataJob();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public CompileDataJob() {
        setTitle("Inserisci i parametri dei lavori");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 551, 293);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        final JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("    OK   ");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try{
                    DataJobManager.azzeraListaLavori();
                    int numJob=DataJobManager.loadNumeroLavori();
                    LinkedList<Job> listaLavori=new LinkedList<Job>();
                    String id;
                    int time;
                    for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<numJob; rowIndex++){
                            id=(String)(table.getCellEditor(rowIndex,0).getCellEditorValue());
                            time=Integer.parseInt(((String)((table.getCellEditor(rowIndex, 1)).getCellEditorValue())));
                            Job l=new Job(id,time);
                            listaLavori.add(l);
                    }
                        DataJobManager.saveListaLavori(listaLavori);
                        CompileDataJob.this.dispose();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CompileDataJob.this,"Data Saved");
                }catch(Exception ecc){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CompileDataJob.this,"Error during the saving.");
                }
            }
        });
        panel_1.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                CompileDataJob.this.dispose();
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();



        table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class,new MyEditor());

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener() {
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                        int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                        JLabel statusText=new JLabel();
                        if (viewRow < 0) {
                            //Selection got filtered away.
                            statusText.setText("");
                        } else {
                            int modelRow = 
                                table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
                            statusText.setText(
                                String.format("Selected Row in view: %d. " +
                                    "Selected Row in model: %d.", 
                                    viewRow, modelRow));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );


                //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

                        //Set up column sizes.
                        initColumnSizes(table);

        panel_1.add(btnNewButton_1);
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 525, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 213, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 61, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(5)
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 197, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        panel.setLayout(gl_panel);
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);



    }

    private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
        MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();
        TableColumn column = null;
        Component comp = null;
        int headerWidth = 0;
        int cellWidth = 0;
        Object[] longValues = model.longValues;
        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer =
            table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

            comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                                 null, column.getHeaderValue(),
                                 false, false, 0, 0);
            headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            comp = table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(i)).
                             getTableCellRendererComponent(
                                 table, longValues[i],
                                 false, false, 0, i);
            cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Initializing width of column "
                                   + i + ". "
                                   + "headerWidth = " + headerWidth
                                   + "; cellWidth = " + cellWidth);
            }

            column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, cellWidth));
        }
    }

    class MyEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JTextField textField;
        private boolean valueSet;
          public MyEditor() {
            super(new JTextField());
          }

          @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject eo) {
                System.err.println("isCellEditable");
                if (eo instanceof KeyEvent) {
                    KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent) eo;
                    System.err.println("key event: " + ke.getKeyChar());
                    textField.setText(String.valueOf(ke.getKeyChar()));
                    //textField.select(1,1);
                    //textField.setCaretPosition(1);
                    //textField.moveCaretPosition(1);
                    valueSet = true;
                } else {
                    valueSet = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
    }





    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String[] columnNames = {"Nome Job", "Durata"};
        int numJob=DataJobManager.loadNumeroLavori();
        private Object[][] data = getDatiDefaultTabella();

        public class Job {
            public int time; // Should n't this be a long?
            public String jobName;
        }

        public Object[][] getDatiDefaultTabella(){
            Object[][] tabella=new Object[numJob][2];
            for(int i=0; i<numJob; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
                    tabella[i][j]="inserisci dati";
                }
            }

            return tabella;
        }

        public Object[][] getTabella(){
            return data;
        }


        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return numJob;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getRowClass(int r) {
            return getValueAt(r, 0).getClass();
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }


        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            return true;
        }



        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * data can change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                                   + " to " + value
                                   + " (an instance of "
                                   + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  "  + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */

        public void run() {
            try {
                CompileDataJob frame = new CompileDataJob();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That code would not compile, so it is hard to see how you can be using it.

Comment: I have edited and added the whole interface code... so now you could try to compile it if you want.

`DataJobManager` is simply an input\output stream class where I store and load some data, and Job is a simple object with `String id, int time`

Comment: @AndreaF again I deleted my answer here, maybe someone can help you ...

Comment: I hope so^^

thanks anyway... these damn jtables are a pain in the neck

Comment: not, everyting is hidden in `(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)`, `int row, int column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I guess I got it.
I optimized your code a little and deleted stuff I didn't need. You may add it again.

Here is CompileDataJob

```
public class CompileDataJob extends JFrame {
    final boolean DEBUG = false;
  private final JPanel contentPane;

  /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              try {
                  CompileDataJob frame = new CompileDataJob();
                  frame.setVisible(true);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      });
  }

  /**
   * Create the frame.
   */
  public CompileDataJob() {
      setTitle("Inserisci i parametri dei lavori");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setBounds(100, 100, 551, 293);
      contentPane = new JPanel();
      contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setContentPane(contentPane);

      JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
      final JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());

      JButton add = new JButton(" ADD ");
      add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ((MyTableModel)table.getModel()).addRow(new Job(0, ""));
        }
      });

      JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("    OK   ");
      btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              try{
                      DataJobManager.saveListaLavori(((MyTableModel)table.getModel()).getJobs());
                      CompileDataJob.this.dispose();
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CompileDataJob.this,"Data Saved");
              }catch(Exception ecc){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CompileDataJob.this,"Error during the saving.");
              }
          }
      });
      panel_1.add(btnNewButton);
      panel_1.add(add);
      JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Cancel");
      btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
              CompileDataJob.this.dispose();
          }
      });

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();



//      table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class,new MyEditor());

      table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
      table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

              //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
              JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);


      panel_1.add(btnNewButton_1);
      GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
      gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
          gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
              .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                      .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                      .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 525, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                  .addContainerGap())
      );
      gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
          gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
              .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 213, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                  .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 61, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                  .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
      );
      GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
      gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(
          gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
              .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGap(11)
                  .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                  .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
      );
      gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(
          gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
              .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGap(5)
                  .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 197, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                  .addContainerGap())
      );
      panel.setLayout(gl_panel);
      contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);



  }
}
```

Here is Job

```
public class Job {
    public int time = 500; // Should n't this be a long?
    public String jobName;
    public boolean processed = false;

    public Job(int time, String jobName) {
        this.time = time;
        this.jobName = jobName;
    }

    public boolean isProcessed() {
        return processed;
    }
}
```

And here is Your TableModel, it is optimizable, but will work...

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final List<Job> objects = new ArrayList<Job>();
    private final String[] columnNames = { "Nome Job", "Durata", "processed" };

    private final Class<?>[] metaModell = new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class, Boolean.class};

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        if (row >= objects.size()) 
            return null;
        Job job = getRow(row);
        switch (col) {
            case 0:
                return job.jobName;
            case 1:
                return job.time;
            case 2:
                return job.isProcessed();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Job getRow(int row) {
        return objects.get(row);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
        if (c < metaModell.length)
            return metaModell[c];
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return col >= 0 && col < columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        Job job = getRow(row);
        switch (col) {
            case 0:
                job.jobName = (String) value;
                break;
            case 1:
                job.time = (Integer) value;
                break;
//          case 2:
//              job.processed = (Boolean) value;
//              break;
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public List<Job> getJobs() {
        return objects;
    }

    public void addRow(Job job) {
        this.objects.add(job);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

As you will see I deleted all MyEditor stuff and the complicated getValues from editor stuff. I instead added a method `addJob()` and `getJobs` to the table model.

Comment: there was a little error, however works fine... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Okay your class do define a CellEditor, but it doesn't do anything the DefaultEditor wouldn't do.

In addition, you do not glue it together.
Your JTable does not know which CellEditor it should use.
You have to tell your table to use your implementation of the editor.
There are multiple ways to do so (e.g. to set a default renderer for a class, which is returned by your tablemodel).
You can also assign a CellEditor directly to the column (
`column.setCellEditor(new MyCellEditor());` --> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: I know this...but the problem is how to implement the right cellEditor to meet the solution of this problem.

Comment: Ok I'm not really sure if I get your problem. You got a table with two columns (1. column is a number -> jobnumber, 2. column is a String). So you have to set 2 default editors for Integer.class and String.class. Object.class may do what you want, but your get*Class() methods do return concrete classes so the concrete editor is used as well (and as far as I know a default editor for String is also registered)

Comment: What I wanted to say is: try `table.setDefaultEditor(Integer.class,new MyEditor());` and `table.setDefaultEditor(String.class,new MyEditor());` instead of `table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class,new MyEditor());`

Comment: column 1 is a String Job, column 2 is a number int... the table is displayed correctly but when you try to get the data from cell editor to extract the new data from the edited `getCellEditor(row, column)` returns only the data of the last cell and not the data of the passed coordinates.

Comment: Ok I still don't get your problem. Why do you want to get the value from the cellEditor? Your data is stored in your table model. Ask it, do not bother the cell editor. It is just a helper to get your table model edited. Java takes care of transporting your model data to the editor and back to the model. If you want to add a new entry to your table model do something similar to this -> tblModel.addItem(new Job("", 0)); and after that you can edit the cells in your table via gui (so you do not have to invoke the cell editor manually)

Comment: when the table is opened is filled with default value without cellEdidor I cannot access the user input in the various cells edited by user... I need only to get the whole table edited by the user to store it in a list, if you have a working solution that doesn't use cell editor you are welcome... but I don't know how to do this without cellEditor

Comment: There are several problems with your code. Figure out what you want your application to do. Remember -> table model holds your table data (in your case I guess a list of Jobs). Your `DataJobManager` has this information. So you should do two things: 1. get all data from your `DataJobManager` and pass it to your TableModel => new MyModel(DataJobManager.getAllJobsAvailable()); 2. all changes made to the DataJobManager and/or to the table model must be transported to the other one (DataJobManager or table model). For this use addTableModelListener in your TableModel.

Comment: After you have done that, editing shouldn't be a problem anymore. I cannot help you in more detail, because your code does not compile and after some fixes it doesn't run, so I guess you should fix your architecture first (a first step is to stop randomly accessing DataJobManager everywhere in your application)

Comment: DataJobManager is a simple class that store and load a List of job and a job counter in a file using input stream and output stream and these unfortunately aren't edited automatically if you edit the table if I don't implement the right methods(and seems significantly more harder to implement this solution)... the code that I have edited yesterday should compile if DataJobManager cause error you should use simply an int for int where there is `numJob=DataJobManager.loadNumeroLavori();`and in the ok listener  use a `System.out.println` to print the list

Comment: ok and what do you want to do with the table? create new jobs or just edit the old ones or both?

Comment: I need simply a table with 2 column(String,int) and n rows, that when I click Ok button, saves  in a linked list, all data that the user edits in the cells. :)

Comment: with the saved data create n jobs (one for each couple String, int) to store in a new LinkedList<Job>